# awk how to print "NA" if one of the output field is empty

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am trying to print 'NA' if the output columns are empty, like

```sh
$cat file.txt
111||aa1|11a|key
|bbb|aa2|22a|key
333|ccc||33a|key
444|ddd||44a|key
555|eee|aa5|55a|key
```

If I do awk I am getting like

```sh
$awk -F'|' '{print $1,$2,$3}' file.txt
111  aa1
 bbb aa2
333 ccc 
444 ddd 
555 eee aa5
```

But I want the empty columns to be filled with 'NA' like below

```sh
111 NA aa1
NA bbb aa2
333 ccc NA 
444 ddd NA
555 eee aa5
```

tried:

```sh
$awk -F'|' '{print '!$1 $1="NA"}',$2,$3}' file.txt 
awk -F'|' '{print $1,if($2=="") $2="NA",$3}' file.txt
```

Please help me in filling "NA" if the field is empty

Comment: Why are you printing only 3 columns (if there are more) ?

Comment: Your output doesn't have pipes as delimiter, is that how you want?

Comment: Related: [Replacing missing value blank space with zero](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53448), [Replace blank fields with zeros in AWK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801602), [Replace empty values in a column with 'UNKNOWN'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158489)

Answer (score 4):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk -F '|' '{sub(/^\|/, "NA|"); gsub(/\|\|/, "|NA|"); print $1, $2, $3}' file
```

```
111 NA aa1
NA bbb aa2
333 ccc NA
444 ddd NA
555 eee aa5
```

another variant:

```
awk -F '|' '{for(i=1; i<=3; i++) if ($i=="") $i="NA"; print $1, $2, $3}' file
```

```
111 NA aa1
NA bbb aa2
333 ccc NA
444 ddd NA
555 eee aa5
```

Comment: Brutal but effective!  =)

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk -F'|' '{print f(1), f(2), f(3)} function f(n){return ($n=="" ? "NA" : $n)}' file
111 NA aa1
NA bbb aa2
333 ccc NA
444 ddd NA
555 eee aa5
```

Comment: Some golfing `f(n){return($n?$n:"NA")}`

Comment: @Jotne That would fail if `$n` had the value `0`.

Comment: A more modular version if there are more fields. `awk -F'|' 'function f(n){return ($n==""?"NA":$n)} {NF-=2;for(i=1;i<4;i++) $i=f(i)} 1'`  Will function in this case be declared for every line?

Comment: It'll be declared once but called for every line. That `NF-=2` is still non-portable and you don't need it if you're looping to a specific field number.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an idiomatic way to do it, but you could use the ternary operator to shorten it a bit:

```
awk -F'|' '{n="NA";print ($1!=""?$1:n),($2!=""?$2:n),($3!=""?$3:n)}' file.txt
```

Output:

```
111 NA aa1
NA bbb aa2
333 ccc NA
444 ddd NA
555 eee aa5
```

Comment: That would produce a syntax error on some awks (e.g. OSX/BSD awk) due to the unparenthesized ternary expression in that context. Always parenthesize your ternary expression to avoid that issue and improve readability - ternaries are hard enough to read when they ARE parenthesized!

Comment: Thanks  @EdMorton. Btw, good idea to [use a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59185247/171318) !

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk`

```
awk -F'|' '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++)$i=$i!=""?$i:"NA";NF-=2}1' file
111 NA aa1
NA bbb aa2
333 ccc NA
444 ddd NA
555 eee aa5
```

It may be better to also add some parentheses:

```
awk -F'|' '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++)($i=$i!=""?$i:"NA");NF-=2}1' file
```

Comment: That would fail if `$n` had the value `0` and the effect of decrementing NF is undefined behavior per POSIX so some awks will remove fields as you want, but others will ignore it and others still could do anything else. An unparenthesized ternary expression will also produce a syntax error in some contexts in some awks (e.g. try `awk 'BEGIN{print 1==2?"foo":"bar"}'` using OSX/BSD awk or `awk 'BEGIN{print 1>2?"foo":"bar"}'` using GNU awk or I suspect any other awk) so it's best to always parenthesize them for that reason and to improve readability.

Comment: @EdMorton  Updated.